# Recyclerview onCreateViewHolder being called despite all views being recycled?

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-recyclerview, android-profiler

***Short Story:***
I have a (pre-caching)Custom `LinearLayoutManager`, `RecyclerView`, Custom `RecyclerView.Adaptor`, Custom `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` setup. I have only one viewType and lightweight binding functions. Its really nothing super special which is why I hoping I don't need to post code. I also don't want to confuse with all the irrelevant code.

The issue I have is that despite not failing to recycle any views, onCreateViewHolder is still being called occasionally (after initial row inflations) leaving me wondering that maybe I have a memory leak? Do you think this is the case and why? What is deciding that my app still needs to create more views instead of recycling?

I will add one thing that maybe factoring in somehow. My rows have two visual states (they expand and collapse) and it kinda appears that having a more random mix of rows in different states worsens the problem.

***Full Story:***
Ive noticed an occasional hiccup in the smooth scrolling of my `RecyclerView`. Using android studio's profiler, I have noted the following:

1. All my `bindViewHolder` methods are plenty fast and are not holding back the scrolling.
2. `OnCreateViewHolder` is what is causing the stuttering. This explains why there is always a few stutters during the first scroll. Moreover, its the inflation thats taking a ridiculously high percentage of the cpu time.
3. With an item/row layout constructed using `ConstraintLayout`, the `onMeasure` functions' poor performance, destroyed the scrolling performance on weaker devices.
4. With an item/row layout constructed using `LinearLayout`s, the performance improved drastically. However, the inflation of views still takes long enough to cause hickups.

With this information, I have simplified my row item's layout as much as possible making sure to use `LinearLayout`s. Irregardless, the rendering of the recyclerview's items shouldnt result in stuttering after the first items come on screen because one, the rows are all the same except for the data binded to them and two, the `RecyclerView` is supposed to recycle the rows. So `onCreateViewHolder` should be called a lot initially and then rarely called again. What about pre-caching? I have found this to be one reason that new viewholders are requested when scrolling. I set the cache and created a custom `LinearLayoutManager` that overrides the pre-caching (pre-fetching?) method called `getExtraLayoutSpace(RecyclerView.State state)` and adjusted the two so that there are enough existing recyclable views to cover the request during scroll. My tests confirm that after initial scroll, new views arent requested when transitioning into scrolling state.

All that and I have two issues remaining. One of them being that `onCreateViewHolder` is called every so often during the use of the app and this causes a little hiccup. I put a `Log.w()` inside `onFailedToRecycleView()` to see any views are not being recycled and it looks like views are being recycled. So now I think there is some memory leak and the memory profiler shows jumps in memory usage often occuring when `onCreateViewHolder` is called.

Answer (score 0):

The three questions I posted where,

1. Do I have a memory leak because Recyclerview keeps creating Viewholders?
2. Why do I have a memory leak?
3. What is deciding that my app still needs to create more views instead of recycling?

I believe I have essentially found the solution to the 2 out of 3 of the questions or the respective underlying problems.

Inside `Recyclerview` class is a `Recycler` class and `RecycledViewPool` class. ***The internal `Recycler` object is what makes a request to the `RecycledViewPool` object for an available detached scrap viewholder to recycle*** if it doesnt already have an attached scrap viewholder to recycle. And specifically, this search for a recyclable viewholder happens inside `Recycler`'s `getViewForPosition(int position)` function. If (inside this function), a recyclable view is not found, then `mAdapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.this, type)` is called. This leads to `onCreateViewholder` being called. So to answer the 3rd question, Recycler is deciding when to call onCreateViewholder.

Note that the `RecycledViewPool`'s job is to maintain an array of arraylists of detached scrap viewholders (1d array of an arraylist of each viewType). The maintaining functions include `clear()` , `reset()`, and `setMaxScrap(int viewType, int max)` which do what their names indicate. So the pathway to the solution to second question is to create a custom RecycledViewPool that indicates when scraplist is cleared or diminished so I can track the creation and destruction of scrap views. As far as question 1, this can be solved by using `setMaxScrap(int viewType, int max)`. Also, on initialization of the recyclerview we can put a few extra scrapviews in the pool and try to maintain a minimum number of scrapviews which can probably be done with a listener.